# Synchronous action with redux-thunk

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

For my react web app, I want to check for authentication token when a protected link is accessed. Here's the action for checking auth:

```
export const checkAuthState = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(loadingStart());
        const eAuth = localStorage.getItem('eAuth');
        if (!eAuth) {
            dispatch(logout());
        } else {
            const employeeData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('employeeData'));
            dispatch(authSuccess(employeeData, eAuth));
        }
    };
};
```

But, as it  runs asyncronously, the `eAuth` state in reducer is `null`. So, the user is redirected to login page.
Is there a way to wait till the `eAuth` is set before redirecting. I tried adding `loading` state to `true` until `authSuccess` sets it to `false`, but it  didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

hope it will help you thanks

```
export const checkAuthState = () => {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(loadingStart());
        const eAuth = await localStorage.getItem('eAuth');
        if (!eAuth) {
            dispatch(logout());
        } else {
            const employeeData = await JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('employeeData'));
            dispatch(authSuccess(employeeData, eAuth));
        }
    };
};
```